# Greatest Happiness on Earth?

Tags: sukkot, simchah-joy-happiness, masechet-sukkah

The Mishnah in [Sukkah](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sukkah.5.1?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=bi) (5:1) says, “כָּל מִי שֶׁלֹּא רָאָה שִׂמְחַת בֵּית הַשּׁוֹאֵבָה לֹא רָאָה שִׂמְחָה מִיָּמָיו – Anyone who never witnessed the water drawing of the Simchas Beis HaShoeva never saw simcha his entire life.”

What made the Simchas Beis HaShoeva such an incredible event that it's one of the ultimate forms of happiness?

Comment: I think the statement is figurative. Also, perhaps "festivities" or similar would be a closer translation. The chapter there (in the Talmud, at length) essentially details the joyful occasion illustrating the great joy of the participants and attendees.

Comment: Supplementing above (and, actually the Mishna's description,) The statement is most applicable today as there is no *Bet Hamikdash* around.

Comment: Keep reading. The next _mishnayos_ answer your question.